# UFW rules in place and enabled yet traffic still allowed

Tags: linux, firewall, ufw

I have UFW configured to try and block some unwanted IPs and associated requests.

```
#ufw status |less
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
37.187.183.206             DENY        Anywhere
Anywhere                   DENY        37.187.183.206
198.41.249.59              DENY        Anywhere
Anywhere                   DENY        198.41.249.59
162.159.251.59             DENY        Anywhere
Anywhere                   DENY        162.159.251.59
```

Status active confirms that UFW is enabled and I have 3 IPs here blocked both inbound and outbound.
These rules were inserted with "ufw insert 1" so are the very first rules processed.
However pings and requests are still getting through

```
# ping 193.201.224.10
PING 193.201.224.10 (193.201.224.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 193.201.224.10: icmp_req=1 ttl=52 time=354 ms
64 bytes from 193.201.224.10: icmp_req=2 ttl=52 time=356 ms
```

And so are actual requests

```
#wget 37.187.183.206
--2015-02-13 06:37:23--  http://37.187.183.206/
Connecting to 37.187.183.206:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
```

Any ideas on the cause?

Edit: iptables output as requested

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 27 packets, 1100 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 105M   11G fail2ban-apache-overflows  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
 105M   11G fail2ban-apache-noscript  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
 105M   11G fail2ban-apache  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
    0     0 fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
1107M  884G ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
1107M  884G ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1109 49748 ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1109 49748 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1109 49748 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1109 49748 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 108 packets, 4992 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 746M  274G ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 746M  274G ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  54M 3681M ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  54M 3681M ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  54M 3681M ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  54M 3681M ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-apache (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 105M   11G RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-apache-noscript (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 105M   11G RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-apache-overflows (1 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 105M   11G RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  149  6980 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  54M 7592M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
1042M  875G ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4052K  435M ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID
4052K  435M DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 4
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
6880K  500M ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
6880K  500M ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  54M 7592M ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 638M  263G ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  54M 3681M ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 3915  189K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
 3805  185K LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  54M 7592M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
1042M  875G ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4052K  435M ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID
4052K  435M DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 4
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
6880K  500M ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
6880K  500M ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  54M 7592M ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 638M  263G ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  54M 3681M ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 3915  189K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
 3805  185K LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
6880K  500M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  16M  979M ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW
  38M 2701M ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            37.187.183.206      
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       37.187.183.206       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            198.41.249.59       
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       198.41.249.59        0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            162.159.251.59      
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       162.159.251.59       0.0.0.0/0           
   10   600 DROP       all  --  *      *       220.181.108.153      0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       220.176.172.157      0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       222.70.153.55        0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       94.153.11.136        0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       178.63.95.202        0.0.0.0/0           
  270 10920 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1433
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1433
   11   488 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:81
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:81
 3838  206K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:2222
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:2222
   16   832 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10000
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:10000
 1019 51256 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3096
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:3096
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       27.131.130.17        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       27.131.130.19        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       61.7.147.82          0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
  844 42932 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:21
 1057 63508 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8010
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:8010
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8011
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:8011
```

Comment: Since  `ufw` is only a front end to iptables; could you include the output of `iptables -L -v -n` or `iptables-save`? Responding to ping requests isn't bad

Comment: I have added the iptables upto the relevant section above since it was very long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The short answer:** The rules you created for [**`ufw`**](https://launchpad.net/ufw) are in the INPUT chain which does not impact network traffic originating from system running ufw. You need rules in the OUTPUT chain to manage that traffic.

**The longs answer:** 
The first thing to know in a netfilter firewall (the project name for the kernel packet filter firewall) **rules are checked sequentially** and the fate of the packet (ACCEPT, DROP, REJECT etc.) is determined on a first-match basis.

From your `iptables -L -n -v` you see that you have two complementary technologies that manage your packet filter, both [**`ufw`**](https://launchpad.net/ufw) and [**`fail2ban`**](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) have create ipchains rule sets.

The set of rules managed by fail2ban is processed first, because in the INPUT chain the fail2ban chains are listed first. Those apply to the default webserver ports 80 & 443 or to the ssh port 22.

Since apparently no abusers have been detected no ip-addresses are excluded by the fail2ban rules, they don't match anything yet and use RETURN for further processing of the packet to be done by ufw rule sets.

There you see all your custom ufw rules in the `ufw-user-input` and the counters show indeed what you had already deduced from your `wget 37.187.183.206` command: those rules are apparently never matched.

```
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            37.187.183.206 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       37.187.183.206       0.0.0.0/0 
    ...
```

The reason for that is that,  packets originating from your system, such as those created from your wget command, should be filtered in the OUTPUT chain and never match in the INPUT chain.

All traffic from 37.187.183.206 does get blocked and if your system would be a router/firewall between your server and 37.187.183.206 that traffic would also be blocked, but packets created *by your server* are a special case and are not blocked.

For that special use case they should be in the `ufw-user-output` chain as well.

The reason that ping requests from 37.187.183.206 are allowed is in the chain `ufw-before-input` the rule to accept echo requests (ICMP type 8)  are accepted before the chain with your custom rules is referenced.

```
Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source      destination         
        <snip>
0     0 ACCEPT       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0      0.0.0.0/0   icmptype 8
        <snip>
6880K  500M ufw-user-input  all  --  *  *  0.0.0.0/0      0.0.0.0/0
```